# How to say that a user input item exist in an array? [update]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, while-loop, do-while

I'm a beginner in c# and I have been assigned the following problem: Write a program that recieves an array of 8 positive integers, then recieves a number from the user and then calculates the probabillity of that number being in the array. this should continue until we input -1.
for example this is my string:1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5 and then I input 2, so it should return ./25
this is how the input and output should look like:

input:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

1

2

3(the inputs untill we enter -1)

-1

output:

./125

./125

./125

end (for -1)

so far, this is my code:

Console.WriteLine("enter 8 int values");

```
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] sps = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int[] myint = new int[8];
        myint = Array.ConvertAll(sps, int.Parse);

        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int a;

        int[] yep = new int[8];
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int j = 0; j < yep.Length; j++)
            {
                yep[j] = a;
            }


        } while (a != -1);

        if (a == -1)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < myint.Length; i++)
            {


                for (int j = 0; j < yep.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(yep[j]);

                    if (yep[j] == myint[i])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine((double)count / (double)myint.Length);
                        count++;
                    }
                 else
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(0));
                }
            }
        }
```

I have recieved the string of numbers, converted it into an int array, then I recieved the integer from the user , then I did the algotithm for the output; first I determined that untill we enter -1; the inputs must be stored in an array and then when a==-1 we will movw to if where the condition is checked for existance of the inputs in the first string(which we had already converted into an array at the beginning.) now there is something wrong whith this loops. they dont give me the right answer(the output is 0 -1 0 -1 constantly) and I also dont know how to declare the "end" part. I know that this is a very basic question but I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Use LINQ: *var instanceCount = myint.Count(x=> x == b);*

Comment: This is obviously homework, so LINQ answers are probably not the best for a student to use because then he would not learn as much.

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines:

```
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < myint.Length; i++)
            {
                if (myint[i].Equals(b))
                    count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine((double)count / (double)myint.Length);
```

Output:

```
enter 8 int values
1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5
enter a number
2
0.25
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter 8 int values");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
List<string> myList = new List<string>(line.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

string b = "";
Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
while ((b = Console.ReadLine()) != "-1")
{
    decimal prob = (decimal)myList.Where(s => s == b).Count() / myList.Count();

    Console.WriteLine("probability = " + prob + "\nenter a number");

}
```

You have to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you ask user to enter a string of numbers separated with commas, and split it into a string array (or int array, as you wish):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter array of numbers:");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] numbers = line.Trim().Split(',');
```

Then you ask user to enter desired number he wants to calculate probability for:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
string number = Console.ReadLine();
```

And then calculate the probability like this:

```
double probability = (double)numbers.Count(num => num == number) / numbers.Length;
```

Here is a [link to DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2RM2br)

This should do the task. Comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

**I guess there is better method than this, but still it must work**`

```
int[] List = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3};
int count = 0;
foreach(int d in List)
{
   if(d == reqNo)
   {
    count++;
   }
}
```

***Here reqNo is the number you need to find in array***